# Import data from .xls to table by removing unwanted columns?

Tags: sql-server, excel, ssis, sql-server-2012, dataflowtask

I am creating a SSIS package to import data from .xls(EXCEL sheet 97-2003) to Sql DB.But my .xls file consists of unwanted data for first 4 rows .How can i skip those data.
My file look like

```
Create by:
Modified By:
Date:
Team:
Id     value      sum
1       44         88
2       45         98
```

I tried by i havent seen any advanced option in excel source to skip the rows as we do for .cs file.Can you please guys help me??

Comment: Do you have access to the file?  Can you delete those rows?  The metadata will look at the first row for column headers (if the option is selected on the Excel Source)

Comment: Why not make a copy of your xls and remove the four lines?

Comment: @TTeeple:I cant do it daily because SSIS  package dynamically want to do job every day morning.

Comment: you can skiip the row once the data is in SSIS pipeline using conditional filter.

Comment: See my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4929217/openrowset-for-excel-can-we-skip-several-rows/8903076#8903076

Comment: @Anon:I got your answer ,where i need to use that Query to skip rows?